# Spring hibernate mysql default column default values

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have some columns in a table that i have given some default value in mysql. I want to be able to use the default values i set in a query that i run with java hibernate

I have this code

```
 String updated_value = (String)query.uniqueResult();

@SuppressWarnings({
"rawtypes",
"deprecation"
})
Query theQuery = currentSession.createSQLQuery("update trades set trade_end_value = ?1 ,trade_status = 'DONE', trade_end_value_worker_status ='DONE' where trade_end_value_worker_status='UNDONE' AND trade_status='UNDONE'");
             theQuery.setParameter(1, updated_value);
             theQuery.executeUpdate();
```

When i try the code on mysql workbench, it runs and updates but when i do it inside of java,I get this error

> java.util.NoSuchElementException
>           at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.BasicFormatterImpl$FormatProcess.perform(BasicFormatterImpl.java:118)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.BasicFormatterImpl.format(BasicFormatterImpl.java:75)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:89)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:77)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:167)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1995)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1925)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1903)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:351)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2702)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2685)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2517)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2512)

Comment: Aren't parameters 0-based? According to these examples https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.hibernate.Session&method=createSQLQuery  you need to use `setParameter(0, updated_value);`

Comment: The error is caused by a race condition, usually when you have an insert and update sharing the same session as explained here https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=945693&sid=4e4c4f09573fb893f7117212b0f2a1b9

Comment: Your error seems a bit different as it is thrown in logger while parsing query. I think that because params are 0-based but you used `1` as index Hibernate decided that enumeration should have 2 elements but it actually had only one.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but the query once i remove one of the queries. I am doing select then update using the same session.